# Several Custom Audience Retargeting pixels on the same page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

If one were to place several retargeting pixels into one webpage, how would that be done?

The code below is the default pixel you're given which tracks and adds customers to your custom audience:

```
<script>(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
  _fbq.push(['addPixelId', '12345']);
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', 'PixelInitialized', {}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" border="0" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=12345&amp;ev=NoScript" /></noscript>
```

The only unique part of this snippet is the `ad_account_pixel_id`, **12345** in the example. With Facebook **Conversion** pixels adding several IDs is very simple, as the initialization is all general. But here, an id is added by `_fbq.push(['addPixelId', '12345']);` to later be tracked with `window._fbq.push(['track', 'PixelInitialized', {}]);`, where `PixelInitialized` is a default callback event.

I want to combine several Retargeting Pixels using the least amount of code possible, so adding them one after the other is not an option. Can I simply add a new `_fbq.push(['addPixelId', '99999']);` after and track that? My gut tells me these will interfere, why else wouldn't the initialization be general?

The reason I'm asking and not testing by trial and error is that the data is updated per 100 visitors, which would make the testing process hell. Also, there is no documentation of the `fbq` class. So if anyone has encountered this, or has a clue anyway, please do help!

Appreciate any response, even if not in the form of an actual answer.

Thanks in advance,

Fredrik

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just add a new call to _fbq.push() with the other ids you want to track as explained below:

**Conversion and Custom Audience Events Together**

There are many occasions where you may want to activate both a Custom Audience and a Conversion Event on a single page load. For example, on an order confirmation page, you may want to activate a Conversion Pixel to measure and optimize Ad Performance for Purchase events and values. At the same time, you would also want to activate a Custom Audience Pixel in order to exclude recent purchasers from an ad.

To do this, include both _fbq.push() calls underneath the setup code on page load:

```
function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
  _fbq.push(['addPixelId', '<ad_account_pixel_id>']);
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
// Custom Audience Event
window._fbq.push(["track", "Purchase", {
  price: 500,
  product_id: 1234,
  product_category: 'Apparel & Acessories > Shoes'
}]);
// Conversion Event
window._fbq.push(['track', 987654321, {
  currency: 'USD',
  value: 500
}]);
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/tag-api

Something else, eventhough this is not mentioned in the documentation linked above, make sure to also add the additional images with the other tracking ids. Like:

```
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=REPLACE_WITH_ID_1&cd[value]=0.00&cd[currency]=USD&noscript=1" /></noscript>

<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=REPLACE_WITH_ID_2&cd[value]=0.00&cd[currency]=USD&noscript=1" /></noscript>
```

Where REPLACE_WITH_ID_1 and REPLACE_WITH_ID_2 are your different ids.